# fake LDAP for testing with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, ldap

I have a fake LDAP (basic running script returning data for auth for development purposes) and application, the app is calling LDAP.bind. But the app is using LDAP with AD, so it is binding using SSL encryption of connection and also basic auth, where username is "userprincipalname" aka e-mail address.

I need to use Nginx as a proxy to basic running LDAP fake to find that user in DB. So nginx has to handle bind from the app and passes to LDAP with arguments I need (basically username and dn or base.

I don't know where to begin with Nginx configuration. Should I use any kind of plugin or just simple "proxy_pass"?

can be authenticated by snakeoil cert to encrypt the connection.

Thanks for every advice

Comment: This MIGHT help; But it not clear what you are trying to accomplish. https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ldap-auth

Comment: Thanks, I think it may be the right thing, I must experiment. I need nginx just like a proxy and get data from perl ldap fake server.